# Clearing Python shell

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

How to clear Python shell ?
I am writing a module in python, I want to save it in a file. what is the best way to do it?

Comment: umm, what?  use a text editor to create files.

Comment: Please clarify (by editing) your question. Are you trying to *clear* something or *save a file*? I've tagged your question [idle] as that seems to be appropriate from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> New Window. Put your module in this new window, than save it. To run, just press F5.

Answer (score 2):

Python shell does not get cleared or saved. Perhaps you are using IDLE. It's a confusing piece of software. I'd recommend you to get a real IDE, or at least a proper text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I do in IDLE is `print "\n"*100`

You can also extend Idle and map that to a key. Read Pythoninstall\lib\Idlelib\extend.txt for details

http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/737111-extension-idle-clear-screen-but-how-write-screen

If you are just in console, you can do ( which won't work in IDLE):

```
import os
os.system("cls")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the code into a new file (In file), and save it. To run, you can go to the run section and select "Run Module", or you can simply press F5.